# Facebook (FB.login) not requesting my permissions

Tags: facebook, permissions, scope, facebook-php-sdk

so after updating to the php 3.0 sdk and what not, my `FB.login()` function no longer asks for the permissions I set it to ask. Any one else getting this? Here's some code for you:

```js
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId: 'xxx',
    status: true,
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true,
    oauth : true // enables OAuth 2.0
  });
  // whenever the user logs in, we refresh the page
  //FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function() {
  //  window.location.reload();
  //});      
};


FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
      FB.logout(function(response) {
        console.log('Logged out.');
      });
    });
  } else {
    console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
  }
}, {scope:'read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access'});
```

The way I'm trying to access it, is through an `onClick="FB.login();"`. Can anyone help?

Comment: did you manage to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

Checking the source of the JS SDK I found that they still use **perms** and not **scope** as it it documented.
This is working for me:

> ...onclick="FB.login(handleLoginResponse,
>   {perms:'email,manage_pages,user_birthday'});return false;"...

I hope it helps.

Comment: Just a heads up that this information is out of date. Try this and you'll get "Uncaught Error: OAuth2 specification states that 'perms' should now be called 'scope'.  Please update."

Answer (score 4):

I see something related to this with the JS SDK.  When setting `oauth=true`, the function

```js
FB.login(function (response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    } else {
    console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
}
}, { scope: 'email,publish_stream,user_birthday,user_location' });
```

Correctly requests the extended permissions, but using the `<fb:login-button>` `FBXML` with `scope="email,publish_stream,user_birthday,user_location"` does not.

This looks like a Facebook bug to me...

Answer (score 2):

My problem was similar to you.
I have checked all my javascript to verify if my scope was good in FB.login definition.
Finally I realized that I have a Facebook button in my HTML.

```
<form class="form-signin"><fb:login-button size="large">Facebook</fb:login-button></form>
```

When I have also defined the scope in the FB Button, Facebook ask me correcty to accept new permissions if I change my scope

```
<form class="form-signin"><fb:login-button size="large" scope="<?php print($sFacebookScope);?>">Facebook</fb:login-button></form>
```

Comment: This is the only working solution! scope attribute is needed for XFBML button! This is not mentioned in documentation, and code samples are incomplete.Definitely it is a documentation fault!

Answer (score 1):

I think its because you are calling `FB.logout` within the `FB.login` block.

Effectively what happens is as soon as they log in, they are logged out.

So seperate it like this:

```js
// CALLED WHEN USER LOGS IN
function userLogin() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
            });
        } else {
            console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
    }, {scope:'read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access'});
}

// CALLED WHEN USER LOGS OUT
function userLogout() {
    FB.logout(function(response) {
        console.log('Logged out.');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem until I realized that it was a matter of browser/facebook caching problem. Make sure you have the latest code in your webspace and test your app in a new browser if might be the solution of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that has worked for me was putting the permissions in the login button tag like this:

> <*fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1" data-scope="email">*< /fb:login-button>